# Communicate with multiclient applications

Tags: api, node.js, services, docker

I have a 3rd party application. Basically I need to run one instance of that application for a one user. For 10 users I have to run 10 instances. From my API
I want to communicate with a specific client based on API parameters. Please check the attached image.

[image]

I have two methods and each have some issues.

**1. **using multiple ports****

I can record port number in a database and forward API data to specific instance. For example localhost/instances:4501;

Issues is it's not scalable as there is a limit in port addresses. Also identifying usable ports is another challenge without interface with other applications.

**2. Using docker network**

with this approach I don't need to assign ports , I can just name containers as instance1,intance2 and can forward traffic to specific instance. How ever with this approach I cannot run application with docker. I want to run my application without docker as well.

Which approach is better? And is there any other best way to achieve this?
thank you

Comment: Do your API and Clients communicate over http?

Comment: @Darem Both  api and clients exist in the server  .Yes I'm using http internal  api to communicate with clients.for example http/localhost:portofclientA or http/clientA using docker network

Comment: And your "application" runs without docker and your clients/instances are docker container?

Comment: @Darem  i have 2 ways to do.i'm trying to find the best way or another method.
I use docker containers and docker network
also i used applications without docker and used ports communicate so different clients has different ports.

Comment: Ok I´m a little bit confused by this sentence "How ever with this approach I cannot run application with docker. I want to run my application without docker as well."

Comment: @Darem in the past i used docker. But i could just use application without docker as well.But if in this case if use a docker network it become a hard dependency and i will not be able to run it without docker.